# Appeal to all users

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It seems that our community needs to do a few more things before we can mature to a full site. I appeal for all users to do the following:

- Go through as many questions and answers (especially zero-vote questions) and vote accordingly (We need to give each other reputation because in a full-site the privilege requirements will become much much higher, and in order for the community to run itself we need users that have access to moderator tools (2k rep for beta but 10k rep for a full site))
- Check on closed questions and decide if they can be salvaged and reopened. (Beta needs 500 rep to allow you to vote to reopen/close, but a full site requires 3000 rep)
- Check on questions with close votes and decide if it truly needs to be closed if not suggest how to salvage the question or edit it to improve.
- Actively promote this site to anyone you think would find this site useful.
- Suggest more things that we can do here to the community so that we can move this site closer towards graduation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good luck.  However, I am personally not interested in making conscious effort aimed at graduation of the website.  This is because if we need conscious effort to graduate beta, we will not probably be able to keep that level of effort after graduation and therefore we should not graduate beta until we can naturally attain the necessary level of activity for graduation.

Comment: Good point. It was myopic of me. My intention was to try to deal with what I perceive to be users being apprehensive when voting. There are many questions with a lot more views than votes, which seems to indicate a large number of non-voters.

Comment: @Flaw Don't forget that views can still come from people who aren't registered and therefore can't vote. Even if a question has 100 views, it's possible (but unlikely) that all 100 of those views are from people who can't vote. (I'm using can in the sense that they don't care to sign up and vote, not that they are eternally unable to vote, lol)

Comment: There's an additional consideration. Many of the users here (myself included) are curious to see the discussions and explanations, but do not feel qualified to judge if an answer is 'good' or not after a certain level of complexity. This obviously doesn't excuse our lack of voting for questions, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where I read this, but somewhere someone was talking about vote-atrophy, where a SE site comes to a point where N number of votes is considered "good". It varies from site to site, but in any case if a question reaches that number, someone might abstain from voting because they see it is already "good enough". I think I'm guilty of this myself. I think we just need to put out there that we should be making a conscience effort to vote on a question/answer regardless of the number of votes it has already received.

Also, this post also has good advice to follow: [You don't have to get a green check to be right, or to be helpful](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/639/you-dont-have-to-get-a-green-check-to-be-right-or-to-be-helpful)